# Play Video in html5 using GWT

Tags: html, gwt

I have game (build in libgdx) 
I use GWT to convert it to html5

I need to show cinematic videos in it

is there any way to do it? I need to work my game on cross platform

Comment: In your previous questions mark one answer as the solution. This can be the answer with the highest votes or the one that helped you the most.

Comment: Please read the FAQ as it explains basic StackOverflow understanding - http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used http://code.google.com/p/gwt-html5-video/downloads/list

to show videos

```
    VideoWidget videoPlayer = new VideoWidget(true, false, null);

    List<VideoSource> sources = new ArrayList<VideoSource>();
            sources.add(new VideoSource(video, VideoType.MP4));

        videoPlayer.setSources(sources);
        videoPlayer.setPixelSize(960, 640);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the widget [Video](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/media/client/Video.html). It represents HTML5 tag `video`. But this widget may not work properly on all browsers.

You can read about other HTML5 features supporting by GWT in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideHtml5).

Comment: Your first link gave me a 404.  Here's an updated link.  http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/media/client/Video.html

Answer (score 1):

Add this Tag to your UIBinder (*.ui.xml) if you use one,

```
<g:HTML ui:field="mediaContainer" styleName="mediaPlayer">
 <video autoplay="true" controls="controls" ui:field="mediaPlayer" height="100%" width="100%">
 </video>
</g:HTML>
```

Now Add the Following Code in your UiBinder Java Part or in a Presenter if you wish to do so. I added this to my presenter part. Hope you have your UiField Objects Declared with Proper Getters and Setters

```
private Element videoSource = null;
private Element videoPoster = null;

// FOR PLAYING A VIDEO URL THAT THE USER ENTERS
    public void loadTool(String videoUrl) {
        if (videoSource != null) {
            videoSource.removeFromParent();
            videoPoster.removeFromParent();
        }
        videoSource = DOM.createElement("source");
        videoPoster = DOM.createElement("img");
        videoSource.setAttribute("src", videoUrl);
        videoPoster.setAttribute("src",
                MyContants.VIDEO_TEST_IMAGE);
        videoPoster.setAttribute("alt",
                MyContants.VIDEO_TEST_IMAGE_ALT);
        videoSource.getStyle().setVisibility(Visibility.VISIBLE);
        videoPoster.getStyle().setVisibility(Visibility.VISIBLE);
        videoWidget.getMediaPlayer().appendChild(videoSource);
        videoWidget.getMediaPlayer().appendChild(videoPoster);
        videoWidget.getMediaContainer().setVisible(true);
    }
```

**Hope this Helps in Some way**